# Simple tool to translate T-SQL query to SQLite?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I would like a simple tool to translate a query from T-SQL (SQL Server) to SQLite.

Does anyone knows one? Thanks.

Comment: Is that a huge query that can't be modified manually?

Comment: No, but I wish I could do it in a few seconds instead of a few minutes =/